# Transform 3d point using angles

Tags: math, vector, transform, angle

I have a 3d point that I would like to rotate using angles (yaw, pitch and roll) around { 0, 0, 0 }.

How would I go about it, without converting the angles into a matrix?

Comment: I would say this is a quick search on your favorite search engine.

Comment: I searched, everything was related to quaternion angles

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't really "convert angles into a matrix".  Strictly speaking, rotations are linear transformation and are in general comprised of an angle and an axis (vector) about which the rotation occurs.  The two easiest approaches to define an angle / axis rotation is by using quaternions or rotation matrices.  There may be other approaches, but these two methods are used largely because they are the easiest methods anyone has proposed to date.  Of the two, I personally prefer quaternions for rotations since they are easier to implement and require fewer arithmetic operations.  3x3 matrices have the benefit that they are able to handle general 3D->3D [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map); 4x4 matrices can perform general 3D->3D [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) on 3D vectors.

If you want to use separate rotations for yaw, pitch and roll, you should probably review issues related to [Euler Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).  You can model these using either rotation matrices or quaternions.  Both approaches will essentially be equivalent.  It's simply a matter of defining a sequence of angle / axis pairs and multiplying them to get the final rotation.  That rotation is then applied to whatever points you have to arrive at the rotated value.